# Identify what is on the stack and heap in a multi-threaded program?

Tags: java, multithreading, heap-memory, stack-memory

```
public class Example {
    private int stateVal = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Example a = new Example(50); // Line 4
    }
    public Example(Integer stateVal) {
        this.stateVal = stateVal; // Line 7
        Thread a = new MyThread("Thread-a");
        Thread b = new MyThread("Thread-b"); // Line 9
        a.start();
        b.start();
        while ((a.isAlive()== false ) || (b.isAlive()== false))  {
            try { 
                this.wait(1000); 
            } catch ( InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        synchronized ( this) {
            this.stateVal++;
        }
    }
    private synchronized int getStateVal() {
        return this.stateVal;
    }
    public class MyThread extends Thread {
        int stateVal = 0;
        public MyThread(String name) {
            super(name);
        }
        public void run(){
            for (;;) {
                System.out.println(this.getName());
                System.out.println(Example.this.getStateVal());
                System.out.println(this.stateVal);
                this.stateVal++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, if you were to represent the stack(s) and the heap for the this multi-threaded program at each of those lines

Line 7

Line 9

Line 4

From this I want to understand how Java allocates memory in heap and in stack.
perhaps represent this in a way, indicating reference/object links, which represent the state of the program when the flow of control has just carried out the instructions given on. How would you represent it? A diagram could perhaps help?

Comment: The stack and the heap unusually function the same way in any Java program, multithreaded or not.

Comment: @varun - You are wrong.. JVM doesn't create a heap for object a. It allocates object a on the *already created* heap. The stack is a different memory location, each thread will have its own Java stack, Native stack and java program counter.

Comment: Also, I recommend you Google before to ask: http://bit.ly/1yb9jQR, http://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-memory-vs-stack-memory-difference, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/65281/stack-and-heap-memory-in-java

Comment: @TheLostMind I just wanted to add that as far as I know, in some cases the JVM _might_ need to allocate more memory and grow the heap if `Object A` is too big to fit and the heap is currently less than max heap size.

Comment: for example on line 7
is this correct? what about the other lines?
http://i.stack.imgur.com/a2lTB.png